# connect to Rest API in iOS and map data with json

Tags: ios, json, core-data, restkit

I have a json file from Rest API on server I want to connect to the server and use get post and put,would you please help me in this implementation,

Here is my server API end points:

GET /

GET /calls/[:id]

POST /calls

PUT /calls/:id

Here is my json file:

```
[
{
"applicant": "Blue",
"company": "Telus",
"status": "active",
"wellType": "Development",
"latitude": 56.715866,
"longitude": -118.281757,
"_id": "52c98833954a010200000"
},
{
"applicant": "Red",
"company": "Bell",
"status": "active",
"wellType": "Development",
"latitude": 56.715800,
"longitude": -118.281777,
"_id": "52c9883f954a010200000"
}
```

I set up Restkit on my xcode, create Entity for my core data but I don't know how to connect and get and post my methods

I appreciated if you can provide me the code and also appreciate any tutorial 
:

Thanks in advance!

Here is my Entity class

Call.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * applicant;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * wellType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * company;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * status;
```

my method in AppDelegate.m for connection

```
- (void)configureRestKit
{

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

// initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

// setup object mappings
RKObjectMapping *calleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Call class]];

//I don't know how to map my data and print them in Log 

 }
```

Comment: I find MKNetworkKit to be much simpler, easier to use, complete, better maintained, and better documented than RestKit: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/ios-components/mknetworkkit/

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare thanks for comment,but I want to do it with restkit do you know how to do that?

Comment: I cannot. I tried using `RestKit` for about a week, was able to get basic `GET` requests working, then I discovered `MKNetworkKit` and I threw out `RestKit` and had `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` all working within an hour of switching. If you're not forced to be using `RestKit` (IE, because you have a boss making you or are on a team that's already using it) then I'd suggest switching.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare do you have sample of MKNetworkKit for GET, POST, PUT

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare does MKNetworkKit offer any mapping features?

Comment: @Wain - No, it doesn't have that "feature". It nicely manages the low level networking for you without trying to force other unrelated crap on you.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare if you don't want mapping then you should never have been using RestKit... And, in that case, why not AFNetworking?

Comment: @Wain - Hm. Not sure why I didn't use AFNetworking. I used it once several years ago but I think I entirely forgot that it even existed before I did the research for my current project. The only libraries that I looked into during my research were RestKit, MKNetworkKit, and the possibility of rolling my own.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post shows a `GET` in their first example: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/

The important things to do are:

1. Alloc an instance of `MKNetworkEngine` and use `initWithHostname:portNumber:apiPath:` to initialize it.
2. Create an `MKNetworkOperation` using `MKNetworkEngine`'s `operationWithPath:params:httpMethod:ssl:` instance method.
3. Add completion handlers to the `MKNetworkOperation` instance using `addCompletionHandler:errorHandler:` (Technically optional, but it'd be weird to not use this because then you'd have no way of knowing if an operation had completed or failed without polling).
4. Use `MKNetworkEngine`'s `enqueueOperation:` method on the `MKNetworkOperation` so that it'll get started as soon as a network is available.

Here's some code I've written that posts some data as a `POST` using MKNetworkKit.

```
+ (MKNetworkOperation *)signup:(NSString *)username email:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password success:(SuccessBlock)success error:(MKNKErrorBlock)errorBlock {
    MKNetworkOperation *operation = [self.sharedEngine operationWithPath:@"signup/"
                                                                  params:@{@"username": username,
                                                                           @"email"   : email,
                                                                           @"password": password}
                                                              httpMethod:@"POST"
                                                                     ssl:YES];
    [operation addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {
        self.sharedEngine.username = username;
        self.sharedEngine.password = password;
        CHECK_NULL_EXEC_BLOCK(success);
    } errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
        CHECK_NULL_EXEC_BLOCK(errorBlock, error);
    }];
    [self.sharedEngine enqueueOperation:operation];
    return operation;
}
```

It's not the greatest example since I wrote it without ever planning to share it as an example, but the rest of my methods are probably even harder to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route for posting. and you also need to setup your mapping. You've only declared it thus far.

```
[calleMapping mapKeyForPath:@"applicantid" toAttribute:@"applicantid"];
[calleMapping mapKeyForPath:@"wellPath" toAttribute:@"wellPath"];
....etc....

[[objectManager router] setMapping:calleMapping toResourcePath:@"/calls" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPost]
```

then for GET you need to set the serialization mapping (and most likely it's the inversion of the original mapping)

```
[[objectManager mappingProvider] setSerializationMapping:[calleMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[Call class]];
```

A lot more info here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping